# Copy a block of text and use it to replace a second block of text using vim

Tags: vim

I'm using vim and I'm trying to change from a file like this:

```
Block 1                                                              
2.41257378185832E+000   T   2.41257378189357E+000
5.195589598713250E-002  T  5.195589598548488E-002
-4.492502140894707E-002 T -4.492502141060845E-002
3.875548288763534E-002  T  3.875548288654486E-002
Block 2                                                              
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
```

to a file like this one:

```
Block 1
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
Block 2                                                              
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
0.000000000000000E+000 F   0.000000000000000E+000
```

I've been searching for an answer for the problem but I didn't find an easy way.
What I found is that I can:

- Select the first block: ctrl-v move "ay
- Select the second block: ctrl-v move c ctrl-o "aP

But this method is a little slow because I have to do this in so many blocks, not just one.
Is there a way to paste text and at the same time replace it by the text that is below it without having to select the text that is going to be junked and the text that is going to be replaced?

Comment: the `Block1,2` text is in your file too? or you just added it? how do you define a "block"? by empty lines?

Comment: A block is a group of 4 lines that contain the letters T or F in my example.

Comment: the Block1,2 text is in my file too.

Answer (score 0):

- move to the first line of the block you want to cp, press `"a4Y`
- `:let @q='4dd"ap'`
- move to the first line of the block you want to replace, press `@q`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very precise, so here are some general hints:

- If following blocks have the same size as the originally selected one, you can use `1v` at the start of the new block to select it.
- The paste-over-selection has the side effect of losing the pasted contents; i.e. you have to re-select the original and yank again if you need this once more. My [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703) offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command.
- If you have multiple such blocks to process, a *macro* can be useful. Record it in such a way that as the last action, the cursor moves to the next block. This way, you can repeatedly invoke it (or even turn it into a *recursive macro* that repeats itself until the end of the buffer.
- Alternatively, the `:global` command can be used to search for (e.g. beginnings of blocks), and then perform a command there; also normal mode ones via `:normal`.